# Encrypting Marketing Cloud Reports

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, automationstudio, platform-encryption, sfmc-business-unit

So I'm creating a reporting definition to run in an automation. I would like the report to be .pgp encrypted and dropped onto the SFTP. The reporting definition in Marketing Cloud allows a drop onto the SFTP, but I don't see anywhere where you can encrypt a report. Is there some automation studio function that performs encryption on reports on the SFTP, or is it possible to encrypt on the send from Marketing Cloud?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a **File Transfer Activity** in Automation Studio:

> Create a file transfer activity to move, unzip, encrypt, or decrypt a
>   file in Marketing Cloud Automation Studio.

1. Click Create Activity.
2. Select File Transfer.
3. Provide a name, external key, and description.
4. Complete the fields on the Properties page.
5. Select Manage File or Move a File From Safehouse.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_create_a_file_transfer_activity.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

Comment: But does the file automatically go to the safehouse as well as the SFTP when you export it to SFTP?